# Download attachments from exchange online mailbox using powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchange-server, microsoft-graph-mail

I need to connect to Exchange Online Mailbox and download attachments from a specific folder under the inbox.

I did some research and tried a couple of examples, but it is unclear what is the best approach to this matter.

I appreciate it if you could give me some examples.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the MS Graph API for such tasks, see [Get started with the Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/get-started?view=graph-powershell-1.0) and [Outlook mail API overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-mail-concept-overview) for more information.